# Difference between measure and metric in context to information and mutual information

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information, measure-theory

In measure theory, a measure is intrinsic property of the set which informs about the size of the set. On the otherhand an information say a mutual information is a diminishing return property, that tells knowing about certain object, how much information we can obtain about other unknown object.

So I want to know if information is a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory_and_measure_theory), however, a mutual information is a [metric](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-54420-0_21) so I want to understand how is information a measure while mutual information is a metric?

---

As suggested by @whuber, the concrete definition for both measure and metric in-context to the question are as follows:

[measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)).

> A measure on a set is a systematic way to assign a number to each
> suitable subset of that set, intuitively interpreted as its size

[metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))

> a metric or distance function is a function that defines a distance
> between each pair of point elements of a set.

Comment: a metric is derived from a measure.

Comment: @Metron Not all metrics are derived from measures (in the sense of the link in the question) nor do all measures produce metrics, at least not in the usual mathematical sense used for metric spaces.

Comment: GENIVI, because we need questions to stand on their own, please include the relevant definitions of "measure" and "metric" in your post.  This is especially important because (a) both terms have a wide range of common definitions and (b) the sense in which your first reference uses "measure" is *not* the sense of measure theory!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045513/measure-and-metric#:~:text=A%20measure%20is%20defined%20on,also%20sort%20of%20a%20distance.

Comment: @whuber good suggestion. Done

Comment: Thank you.  I'm confused, though, because the link you give related to "measure" uses a totally different concept than the definition you give here.

Comment: @whuber Maybe thats the source of my confusion. I did imply measure in the sense of information measure, the link mentions "entropy, KB-Divergence, Mutual Information" as measures. Somehow I am unable to connect mutual information to the notion of sets, cause I understood that the measure they mentioned is in the sense of measure theory, quantifying how the size of the set. If this is not the case then I think that is the answer to my question.

Comment: If you have found an answer to your Q then you can answer your own Q, that is, formally in the answer box, so this does not linger on as unresolved!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen good suggestion but I dont see myself in a position like yourself and dr whuber to be able to eloquently answer the question I raised even if i undersood. If you could contribute to the answer it will be greatly appreciated.